# Awk string manipulation

Tags: awk

I have the string:

```
20120113083000Z
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
2012 01 13 08 30 00 Z
```

ready for the `mktime` command to convert it to a date stamp.

I have at present:

```
echo '20120113083000Z' |    
awk '{print mktime(gensub(/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(.)/,"\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6 \\7",1g,$1))}'
1326439800
```

I know I could use sed or bash to convert it, but I would like to keep it inside an awk process.

Is there a better (shorter or more elegant) way?

N.B. I would like to make it as generic as possible (`gensub` gawk only(?)).

Comment: As far as I know only *GNU awk* supports *mktime*, so *gensub* should be OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo 20120113083000 |  sed 's/../& /g; s/ //' | awk '{print mktime($0)}'
$ echo 20120113083000 |  awk '{print mktime(gensub(/ /, "", "1", gensub(/../, "& ", "g")))}'
```

Comment: Thanks but I really wanted an awk solution. BTW `sed 's/../ &/3g'` works too.

Comment: Thanks for adding the 2nd solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo 20120113083000Z |  awk 'BEGIN { FS = "" } ; { print $1$2$3$4, $5$6, $7$8, $9$10, $11$12, $13$14, $15 }'
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for me:

```
echo '20120113083000Z' |   awk '{gsub(/../,"& ");sub(/ /,"")}1'
2012 01 13 08 30 00 Z
```